# Inserting a 2x2 matrix into a 3x3 matrix

Tags: matlab

```
A = [3 3 6;
     1 5 2;
     8 1 7]
```

> "Copy matrix `A` into a matrix `g`. Allocate a 2 x 2 matrix `h` using the `zeros` command. 
>   Picture a matrix defined as a 2 x 2 matrix of elements in the top right hand corner of 
>   matrix `g`; replace this matrix of elements with matrix `h`."

I have no problem creating the matrix of zeros but I'm not sure how I can add matrix `h` into matrix `g` in the way the question asks.

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a homework question - if so, have you asked your teacher? You can read up on how to index matrices [here](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).

Comment: You can change an individual element of an array like this: `A(1,1)=1`. Using this kind of idea you can replace parts of matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question assumes you know how to index into a matrix.  Let's tackle each part of this question one part at a time, shall we?

1. **Copy matrix `A` into a matrix `g`**:

   Well this is pretty straight forward.  You would just need to do this:

   ```
   g = A;
   ```

   Here, you are copying the matrix `A` into a variable called `g`
2. **Allocate a 2 x 2 matrix `h` using the `zeros` command**:

   You've already done this as I can see in your post:

   ```
   h = zeros(2, 2);
   ```
3. **Picture a matrix defined as a 2 x 2 matrix of elements in the top right hand corner of matrix `g`; replace this matrix of elements with matrix `h`**:

   Now, here is probably where you're getting mixed up.  You can access elements in a matrix either one element at a time, or a **group** of elements at one time.  Here's the first way of doing it:

   ```
   v = A(r,c)
   ```

   `r` and `c` would be the single row and column you want to access in your matrix `A`, and `v` would store this result.  As such, if I did:

   ```
   v = A(1,2)
   ```

   The above would access the value at row 1, column 2.  In this case, we would get `3`.

   You can also access **group** of elements at a single time.  Specifically, you can do this:

   ```
    v = A(r1:r2, c1:c2)
   ```

   This means that you can grab values between rows `r1` and `r2` and columns `c1` and `c2` in your matrix `A`.  So if you were to do something like this:

   ```
    v = A(1:2,2:3)
   ```

   This means that you are grabbing values between rows 1 and 2, and between columns 2 and 3 from `A`.  If you do this, `v` would actually be:

   ```
    v = [3 6;
         5 2]
   ```

   This is precisely what the question is asking.  The upper right corner of `g` would be between rows 1 and 2, and columns 2 and 3.  You want to place `h` into these co-ordinates, so you just have to reverse the operation in `g`:

   ```
    g(1:2,2:3) = h;
   ```

   Therefore, your matrix should now look like this:

   ```
    g = [3 0 0;
         1 0 0;
         8 1 7];
   ```

---

In the comments of your question, there's a great link that teaches you on how you can access elements and assign elements in a matrix and some other good stuff: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html.  It's a good link, so check it out!